# Header and footer not working on class file

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, documentclass-writing

I am trying to make header and footer using `fancyhdr`.

Following the manuals available in other question I have defined header and footer in my class file but they are not shown in output file. Could you please advice what am I doing wrong?

My class file looks like this:

```
    % Definicja klasy
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{KPSEClass}[2016/3/19 KPSE LaTeX class]

% Polskie formatowanie
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\frenchspacing
\usepackage{indentfirst} 

% Nagłówek
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Share\LaTeX}
\lhead{Guides and tutorials}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}

% Domyślny TPL
\LoadClass[twocolumn]{article}

\RequirePackage{xcolor} % Kolory
\usepackage{mdframed} % Boxy

% Formatowanie tytułu

\renewcommand\@maketitle{%

\hfill

\begin{minipage}{0.95\textwidth}
\vskip 2em
\rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}
{\LARGE \centering \textbf \@title \par }
\rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}
\vskip 1 em
{\large \centering \@author \par}
\end{minipage}
\vskip 1em \par
}
```

and document:

```
\documentclass{KPSEClass}

\author{Autor}
\title{Testowy artykuł}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Małe}
Małe\footnote{Nie większe niż bardzo małe} jest piekne.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: You're loading `article` class inside your own class and a customized `\@maketitle`. That will use a different pagestyle ('headings', most likely) for the titlepage. The `fancy` style is applied on the next page(s). (Remove `\maketitle` for a test and you will see your `fancy` pagestyle on the first page as well) You should also replace `\usepackage` in your `.cls` by `\RequirePackage`...

Comment: Correcting myself: `\@maketitle` does not apply a pagestyle, it's `\maketitle` and that uses `plain`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a small fix of the `.cls` file by patching `\maketitle` to use a `\titlepagestyle` which is itself some wrapper command which can be redefined to use some other pagestyle. It uses `fancy` by default.

Now the header and footer settings are applied for the title page (if this is really needed at all...)

```
    % Definicja klasy
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{KPSEClass}[2016/3/19 KPSE LaTeX class]

% Polskie formatowanie
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[polish]{babel}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\frenchspacing
\RequirePackage{indentfirst} 

% Nagłówek
\RequirePackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{xpatch}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Share\LaTeX}
\lhead{Guides and tutorials}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}

% Domyślny TPL
\LoadClass[twocolumn]{article}

\RequirePackage{xcolor} % Kolory
\RequirePackage{mdframed} % Boxy

% Formatowanie tytułu


\newcommand{\titlepagestyle}{fancy}
\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{\titlepagestyle}}{}{}

\renewcommand\@maketitle{%
\hfill

\begin{minipage}{0.95\textwidth}
\vskip 2em
\rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}
{\LARGE \centering \textbf \@title \par }
\rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}
\vskip 1 em
{\large \centering \@author \par}
\end{minipage}
\vskip 1em \par
}
```

Document `.tex`

```
\documentclass{KPSEClass}

\author{Autor}
\title{Testowy artykuł}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\maketitle
\section{Małe}
Małe\footnote{Nie większe niż bardzo małe} jest piekne.

\end{document}
```

[image]